# Docker build for C# core need the internet connection

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, nuget

I am writing in C# .NET core (VS 2017), using the build for linux containers, using docker-compose.

When I build the image (or publish), there is always reference to the internet, because of nuget usage.

Last error encountered (which I persume of downtime on the nuget, but no matter 
 - any downtime should not lead to exception in build/publish).

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.503/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to
>   load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. ...

I want to build the image, even the nuget is down, or even there is no interet connection

The yml file look like this:

```
services:

 myProj:
 image: my_proj
 build:
  context: ./all_projects/base_solution/
  dockerfile: myProj/Dockerfile
```

It seems that "dotnet publish..." command call restore from the internet.

If I run publish with --no-restore, the code not compiled, but I want to restore the nuget packages from my own pre-build of my computer.

How can I do it? With no internet connection? Why should I depend on the internet to restore the nuget at each build?

Why cannot I restore nuget package from my own pre-build image, and not always?! get from nuget (actually nuget packages not change occasionally in my code).

May I just copy the folder from the nuget, and not using "COPY" command?

I did the following:

Build an image from a 'common' project, that uses all the nuget package.

Add a reference in the built-image for the new other image, like this:

Create a new common image:
    # there is no runtime.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY TestDock/TestDock.csproj TestDock/

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish TestDock.csproj -c Release -o /app
```

And at the original image:
    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
    WORKDIR /app

```
# FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build do:
FROM my_common_image AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY TestDock/TestDock.csproj TestDock/

# Added the following. I tried to copy all, but this doesn't help.
# I persume I can copy part of the common build.
COPY --from=build /app /app
COPY --from=build /src /src
COPY --from=build /usr /usr

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish TestDock.csproj --no-restore --no-dependecies -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDock.dll"]
```

I have tried to add an intermediate image, with Dockerfile as following:

```
# This image is base image for all dockers (no need runtime)
#    docker build . -f DockerFile_Common -t docker_common 


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/myProj

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish myProj.csproj -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet pack /src/myProj.csproj -c Release -o /app
```

and use it in my image (that I don't want to build using the internet), instead of:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
```

I did:

```
FROM docker_common AS build
```

I also tried to add the line: "RUN dotnet publish ..." when setting the workdir as the solution folder, and mark the "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" (unmark default "nuget.org").

Still, the above doesn't build correctly.

Comment: You have to build your own NuGet server or a local cache, https://blog.lextudio.com/offline-publishing-asp-net-core-apps-cf22f45158af

Comment: I need to use, i.e, newtonsoftjsoon. One of several files from nuget. It is already in cache (the path is path of the user profile). I didn't find a way to force using the cache.

Comment: Use your own `Nuget.config` file to control that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For not using the internet, you can follow the steps.

What is needed is to publish in visual studio, as following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2

(Alternative publish in command line).

```
dotnet publish myProj.csproj -c Release /p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\ 
   <myprofile>.pubxml /p:PublishDir=<proj_folder>\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish
```

or put in the Post-build event a line like:

```
dotnet publish $(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).csproj -c $(Configuration) 
/p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\PublishProfile.pubxml 
/p:PublishDir=$(TargetDir)publish --no-build
```

... and in the Dockerfile I just did **with need to do "COPY ..." from the relevant publish directory!**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime

COPY MyProjectFolder/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]
```